# Replacing text string within quotes using sed or awk?

Tags: awk, sed

Both sed and g/awk seem very powerful. When I need data manipulated and struggle with syntax I always have answers submitted using both. Personally the syntax of awk is easier for me to grasp (is this common to have a preference?).

I want to spend a few days to trying to study tons of examples of using one or the other, should one specifically be focused on over the other? Does one out perform another in regard to capability? Now onto my question...

I have a .php file that is read and rendered as a json file. It looks like this:

```
<?php
$selectedSystemStateResults = ["Bird", "Cats", "Cows", "Dog", 
"Goats", "Monkey", "Sheep"];
```

1. Using sed/awk how could I specify to change "Dog" to "Ducks" ?
2. Using sed/awk how could I specify to change the 5th variable to
       "Impalas" ?

The first scenario I would know the name of the variable being changed, the second scenario I would just want the change the variable in a static position.

Comment: Are you trying to alter the PHP program or the JSON output? The former is non-trivial in general. For the second, neither awk nor sed is appropriate. Use `jq` or a similar tool that is designed for manipulating JSON.

Comment: The json file is created with another script. I am running a command within the linux cli to pull server stats. a few of those stats need inserted into the above php file (that is the complete file believe it or not), and then the actual script processes that file into a json file to connect to the web via server sent events and a couple by web socket.

Respectfully, even if I were to be outputting directly to json, I think the question would be the same, would it not? How do I insert between the quotes? Currently I am trying to use grep, but I don't think it is the right tool for the job.

Comment: Can sed or awk not process "sometext" as a field and "othertext" as another field?

Comment: It can, as can `sed`, but the point being made is that both are the wrong tools for the job of altering json, and neither have any way of validating that the result continues to conform to json. That is what json manipulation tools like `jq` are used for.

Comment: Understood, thankfully I am not editing json, just the php array above. No worries I found a work around solution. Thank you for the feedback and further explanation.  Likewise jhnc, thank you for trying to keep me from messing up my properly formatted end result.

Comment: wrt your question on shich tool to use for which task - sed is for doing `s/old/new` on simple strings, grep is for doing `g/re/p`, and awk is for every other text manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Disregard, overthinking it.

I simply modified the php file so that I could replace lines for now.

```
<?php
$selectedSystemStateResults = [
"Bird", 
"Cats", 
"Cows", 
"Dog", 
"Goats", 
"Monkey", 
"Penguin"]
;
```